# Is there any way to create columns inside a tikzposter block?

Tags: columns, tikzposter

I am trying to split a tikzposter block within different columns. The columns enviroment works for splitting the poster and insert blocks inside. However the columns environment does not work inside the block.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{myDummyPictureCode.tex}
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Some nice caption for the figure]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [color=red] (0,0) rectangle (20,10) node [midway] {\huge myFigure};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tikzfigure}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}

\usetheme{Autumn}\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}\maketitle

\begin{columns} 
\column{0.7} \block{FigureOutside Block}{
  \lipsum[1]
}

\column{0.3} \block{}{
\input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
}
\end{columns}

% Text and figure Inside the Block
\block{Text and figure Block}{
\begin{columns} 
\column{0.7} \lipsum[1]
\column{0.3} \input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
\end{columns}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Is there anyway to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always use a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{filecontents*}{myDummyPictureCode.tex}
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Some nice caption for the figure]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [color=red] (0,0) rectangle (20,10) node [midway] {\huge myFigure};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tikzfigure}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}

\usetheme{Autumn}\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{columns}
\column{0.7} \block{FigureOutside Block}{
  \lipsum[1]
}

\column{0.3} \block{}{
\input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
}
\end{columns}

% Text and figure Inside the Block
\block{Text and figure Block}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}%
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How you adjust the vertical misalignment between the figure and the text?

Comment: @Sik I would use `adjustbox` package.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, in some cases the usage of `\usepackage{multicol}` might be useful.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}

\begin{filecontents*}{myDummyPictureCode.tex}
  \begin{tikzfigure}[Some nice caption for the figure]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [color=red] (0,0) rectangle (20,10) node [midway] {\huge myFigure};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tikzfigure}
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}

\usetheme{Autumn}\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}\maketitle

\begin{columns} 
\column{0.7} \block{FigureOutside Block}{
  \lipsum[1]
}

\column{0.3} \block{}{
\input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
}
\end{columns}

% Text and figure Inside the Block
\block{Text and figure Block using COLUMNS}{
\begin{columns} 
\column{0.7} \lipsum[1]
\column{0.3} \input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
\end{columns}
}

% Text and figure Inside the Block using minipage
\block{Text and figure Block using MINIPAGE}{
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{minipage}%
  }
  %
  \fbox{
  \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
  \end{minipage} 
  }
  \end{adjustbox}
  }
}

% playing with multicolumn text
\block{Text and figure Block using MULTICOLS}{
  \begin{multicols*}{3}
    \lipsum[1]
    \input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
  \end{multicols*}
}

% playing with multicolumn text
\block{Text and figure Block using MINIPAGE and MULTICOLS}{
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
  \begin{multicols*}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{multicols*}
  \end{minipage}%
  }
  %
  \fbox{
  \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
  \fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
    \input{./myDummyPictureCode.tex}
  \end{minipage} 
  }
  \end{adjustbox}
  }
}

\end{document}
```

[image]