# How to run another tex file from within tikzposter

Tags: pdftex, standalone, csvsimple, tikzposter

I want to run a separate tex file from within tikzposter. Is this possible? I can't find any examples on the internet. I want to do something like this, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183833/is-there-any-way-to-create-columns-inside-a-tikzposter-block/183867#183867) but using a csvsimple package that produces a table with graphics. Here is the tikzposter sample code and a working csvsimple sample code that is contained in the 'other' tex file that I want to input. Thanks in advance.

> tikzposter code

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0mm, innermargin=15mm, blockverticalspace=15mm, colspace=15mm, subcolspace=8mm]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{filecontents*}{csvsimpleCode.tex}
  %%somehow incorporate the csvsimpleCode here?
\end{filecontents*}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}

\usetheme{Autumn}\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\block{Text and figure Block}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\input{./csvsimpleCode.tex}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}
}

\end{document}
```

---

> csvsimple code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{filecontents*}{pseudoDF.csv}
pseudoNSC,pseudoName,strucPath
NSC25348,cLmWrXslh,{\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};}
NSC07145,tMkSERCJs,{\tikz \shadedraw [shading=ball] (0,0) circle (.5cm);}
NSC31876,erBaDLxPN,{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[head to column names,
  tabular=ll>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\linewidth},
  table head=\toprule\bfseries NSC & \bfseries Name & \bfseries strucPath \\\midrule,
  table foot=\bottomrule]%
{pseudoDF.csv}{}%
{\pseudoNSC & \pseudoName & \strucPath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just use the cv.tex as normal to get cv.pdf and in your poster use `\includegraphics{cv.pdf}`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. that's a good option. is that the only way?

Comment: well either you include the results via `\includegraphics` or `pgfpages` etc or you take the body of the cv and just cut and paste it in to the poster and then fix up any command definitions that are needed.  Doing the latter is trickier (depending on the macros used) and the end result may then match the typesetting of the poster more than  that of the original CV which may be a good or bad thing depending on what you want